# Cannot get disk parameters after deployment the node

Tags: maas, openstack

I deploy the maaS node manually. When the status turned to be deployed, I start the machine again. However it says:

"`cannot get disk parameters`"

Could anyone told me what is the possible problems here?

Comment: What do you mean 'manually'? How are you starting the machine, through maas?  When the node gets deployed, it should turn on by itself.  What is giving you that error message, the deployed nodes terminal, or in maas?

Comment: By manually I mean I click on the deploy button on the web UI. My node is kind of special, it is used for storage only so it cannot be turned on remotely. I have to push power button each time for it to get started. This message is given by the node after it shows deployed status on maaS and I pushed the power button to start this node, the screen will say this message when it is trying to import the linux image.

Answer (score 0):

Please check BIOS setting "boot order" and make sure you can boot into local hard disk.

This error message mean "Cannot boot into local disk after deploy", it maybe related to hard disk and BIOS.

You can boot into BIOS ,load default setting , change PXE to first priority, save changes and reset and deploy again.